# Health Monitoring

Tags: asp.net

I built a file cleanup provider by using health monitoring. but I got a problem. It is displayed "Cannot create an abstract class". I configure in web.config that

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="5">
  <providers>
    <add name="FileCleanupProvider" source="FileCleanupProvider" type="System.Web.Management.WebEventProvider"/>
  </providers>
  <eventMappings>
    <add name="FileCleanupEvent" type="System.Web.Management.WebHeartbeatEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
  </eventMappings>
  <rules>
    <add name="CleanupEvent" eventName="FileCleanupEvent" provider="FileCleanupProvider"/>
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

How can I do?

Comment: `System.Web.Management.WebEventProvider` is abstract.  You have to actually inherit from that to instantiate FileCleanupProvider.  e.g. `public class FileCleanupProvider : System.Web.Management.WebEventProvider`

Comment: yes, I use that. But it is not OK. This error is remain.

Answer (score 0):

The [WebEventProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webeventprovider.aspx) is an abstract class. You have to use/implement a class that inherits from this class to use it with Health Monitoring.

Comment: No, I want to clean file every each one hour by using file cleanup provider in health monitoring